# Near-Near-MDS codes

Tags: coding-theory, computational-algebra

I am trying to understand the codes which are not maximum distance separable but are at a distance of 2 from being Maximum Distance Separable. I have trying to find articles specifically related to the topic and trying to find an example of it too. But have been unable to do so. Can someone please guide me as to what material should I refer to or if someone can give an example of generator matrix of space of codewords which ar at a distance 2 from being MDS, that is near-near MDS codes?

Comment: Algebraic geometry codes from curves of genus two would yield plenty of such codes.

Comment: Would you please suggest some reference to read and understand it? @JyrkiLahtonen